# Integracao Angular com PagSeguro

Tags: angular

Estou tentando implementar uma integracao de Angular 8 com a api de gerar boleto do [pagseguro](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference#api-boleto-providers-gerar-boleto).
Fazendo a requisicao pelo POSTMAN, eu consigo gerar sem problemas, pelo angular sou bloqueado pelo CORS.

segue o provider

```
boletoGenerate(body: Boleto): Observable<any>{
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
  })
}
 return this.http.post<Boleto>(this.url, body, httpOptions).pipe();
}
```

Tentei com e sem definir o header, e o resultado foi o mesmo. Alguem ja teve esse problema ou sabe como resolver ?

Comment: Você pode abrir o chrome com o parâmetro --disable-web-security.
Pode criar um certificado localhost, provavelmente só permite req https.
Veja o response headers da requisição.

Comment: Entrei com contato com o PagSeguro, eles me informaram que eu preciso implementar essa funcionalidade no backend. Então pra eu conseguir implementar essa funcionalidade que eu quero no frontend, vou precisar fazer um fluxo de requisição mais ou menos assim: **Frontend cria requisição -> Backend repassa requisição -> Pagseguro retorna boleto -> Backend retorna boleto -> Frontend captura o boleto gerado**

Answer (score 0):

Definir ou não os items que você citou dentro do seu `headers` não fará diferença ao consumir a API. A API é quem deve enviar estes itens no cabeçalho de resposta para o navegador saber quais são as regras para acessá-la. Quando você utiliza o Postman este problema não ocorre porque estas são regras validadas apenas no navegador.

Para ignorar essa validação durante seu desenvolvimento você pode:

- Executar o Chrome com o parâmetro `--disable-web-security`
  Exemplo: execute este comando  `chrome.exe  --disable-web-security`
- Utilizar o Safari: vá até a aba Developer e selecione a opção `Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions`

Sugestão: analise o cabeçalho retornado pela API para ver qual parâmetro está bloqueando sua utilização no navegador dentro do seu ambiente.

Comment: Entendi. Mas então, sempre em dev, vou precisar executar o chrome dessa forma ? No meu provider ( ou código ) nao consigo resolver ?

Comment: @MatheusBarbosa na verdade não! Se o Header que a API está enviando contiver as regras necessárias para que você possa acessar do seu ambiente, não haverá problema. Suponha que a API envie `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://teste.com`, neste caso você precisará abrir o navegador do jeito que eu falei para não ter problemas com CORS. Caso seja `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` você poderá consumir normalmente. Veja quais são os itens no cabeçalho de resposta da API. Se você olhar lá vai saber se terá ou não problemas em produção mas em desenvolvimento pode proceder como na resposta acima.

Comment: @MatheusBarbosa dê uma olhada neste link: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS

Comment: Nao funcionou, tentei iniciar o chrome com essa flag e continuei sendo bloqueado, tbm tentei instalar uma extensão que teoricamente desbloqueia o cors, tbm nao deu certo =/

Comment: @MatheusBarbosa poderia postar a mensagem de erro? se possível, também informe aqui  por favor o cabeçalho de retorno da API através do Postman para podermos dar uma olhada nos headers

Comment: Consegui entrar em contato com pagseguro, eles me informaram que não tem como fazer essa requisição através do front end. É necessário implementar a requisição pelo backend, vou postar a resposta certinha.